# Converting a cout statement into a /printf statement

Tags: c++, c

I am working on converting C++ to C.  How would one covert the following `cout` line into a `printf`?

```
p = int *p, 
pageRequestIndex, frameIndex = int
```

```cpp
cout<<"\nPage "<<p[pageRequestIndex]<<" loaded into Frame "<<frameIndex;
```

Comment: What are the types of `p[pageRequestIndex]` and `frameIndex`?  Please provide a [mcve].

Comment: Have you made an attempt? Are you familiar with the printf format specifiers?

Comment: Sorry they are int variables

Comment: Read more about [`printf`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/printf/)

Comment: @JoseFlores `p` **cannot** be an `int`. Please post more context.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to add clarification or requested information instead of answering in comments.

Answer (score 4):

```
printf("\nPage %d loaded into Frame %d", p[pageRequestIndex], frameIndex);
```

`%d`  --> `for`

Answer (score 1):

```c
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    // 5, 10 are the values of the variables you'd use
    printf("\nPage %d loaded into Frame %d", 5, 10);
    
    return 0;
}
```

Edit: should've posted it right away